# Is LLBLGen similar to codesmith?

Tags: code-generation

Is llblgen just like codesmith?

Is there any tool out there that will create all the CRUD plumbing for you?
And all queries on tables that you can filter by primary key (like Get a user by ID) or by foreign key (get user addresses by UserID if the address table has userID in it) etc.

DO code generators do more than the above?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Is llblgen just like codesmith?" : In many ways, yes. [Frans Bouma is active on SO, I'm sure he will have some input]

[MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx) is a free tool that can create all of your CRUD plumbing.

Comment: It was me, as you can probably already imagine. And I left a comment, it just wasn't against you specifically :) Downvoted for suggesting they are similar (which I'm sure is obvious) and also because it didn't really answer his main question (neither did my post though, so, hard to throw stones there :)

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old post but just in case someone else get here.
By all the means NO, they are just different things. LLBLGen is an Object Relation Mapper (ORM) and CodeSmith is a code generation tool.
Both have templates that generate some code and even if you can write an OR mapper with codesmith it doesn't have all the support classes LLBLGen has.

LLBLGen is in fact a designer that can generate code for NHibernate, Entity Framework or its own LLBLGen Pro framework that are ORM's.

Answer (score -3):

No, it isn't.

CodeSmith is a generation tool. You still need to write the templates, as to how it will generate, and then all the relevant (and substantial) code related to querying/joining/updating/inserting/etc.

CodeSmith + NetTiers is a common 'DAL', but not a great one, IMHO.

LLBLGen is just beautiful, and definitely worth the money, IMHO.

Comment: as I'm sure you are aware: you can also replace llblgen's templates

Comment: Indeed, but LLBLGen is a lot more than just basic code generation. It's certainly similar to CodeSmith + NetTiers, but not CodeSmith alone, IMHO, anyway.

Comment: Given that CodeSmith without templates would be pointless, I take Codesmith to mean  "CodeSmith (+templates)"

Comment: You clearly agree then, unless you want to explain how CodeSmith can be used for something without templates